# What does 连句话也没人说 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 你不必下班后还忙着应酬，一身酒气回家，家人都睡了，**连句话也没人说**。

The sentence would mean something like the following:

> You don't need to cater to the drinking party after the work, which makes you go back home while your family is sleeping.

But I don't understand the last part. What does it mean and specifically how does 也 work in this case? Does it mean "too" or "also" in this case? And what does 连句话 here mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is 连...也... which means something like "not even".

The 也 can be replaced by 都 without changing the meaning.

连句话 should have an 一 in it but the writer is speaking casually/lazily so they omitted it.

So we have:

连  一句话  也  没人说
even a word no-one speak
No-one speaks a word

In context:
家人都睡了，连句话也没人说
Family all gone to sleep, no-one speaking a word

Comment: An idiomatic translation of the whole passage would be: You don't need to bother with socialising after work then coming home smelling of alcohol and not speaking at all with your family because they're all asleep.

Comment: I see. I just found an entry for 连～也 in 连 entry on Pleco. Well, I thought 连句话 is a single word... BTW welcome to Chinese language SE, I hope you keep contributing to this site!

Answer (score 3):

你不必下班后还忙着应酬，一身酒气回家，家人都睡了，我连句话也没人说。

> **我**连句话也没人说。

Means "I got nobody to talk with".

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with Angus' translation in the last phrase

> 连句话也没人说

I think the translation in this context might be:

> (Since all your family fell asleep), you have no one to talk with.

However, this sentence is somehow a bit vague, I have to read it again and again to decide its exact meaning.

Answer (score 0):

你不必下班后还忙着应酬，
You don't need to go socializing after work,
一身酒气回家，
then, reeking of alcohol, return home,
家人都睡了，
when your family are all asleep
连句话也没人说。
without a word being said.

(Better stay out all night, who wants a drunkard at home?)

Answer (score 0):

Well,i am in Hubei,China now.I am a Chinese student.My English is too bad,but i will try my best to tell you what “连句话也没人说” is.Sorry!
“连” means "even"
“句” means "sentence",but you can't understand like this.You know that,in Chinese,there is always a quantifier before each noun,whether it is countable or not.You can understand it as "a" or "an".
“话” means "words".
“也没” means "not".
“人” means "person" or "people".
“说” means "speak" or "say".
In the correct English order,it's 
连 没人 说 句 话
translate in English,it's
even nobody says a word.
I think it is easier to understand it as "there is nobody you can talk with"